# how to create json type document from SolrDocumentList in java

Tags: java, json, solr

```
public Document convertDoctoJson() throws JSONException
    {    
     JSONObject jsd= org.json.XML.toJSONObject(getPhotoGalleryDisplay(null).asXML());

...

here will be code to create json document
 ...    
return jsd;

 }
```

i am getting json response here now I want to return this response as a document. so how do i create json document.Here in method(getPhotoGalleryDisplay(null).asXML()) I am fetching data from solr.

Comment: Could you please specify fully-qualified names of `Document` and `JSONObject` classes? Are those `org.dom4j.Document` (from dom4j library) and `org.json.JSONObject` (from Android lib)? And also signature of `getPhotoGalleryDisplay(...)` would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are those org.dom4j.Document (from dom4j library) and org.json.JSONObject (from Android lib)? ...

Comment: Sorry, what do u mean? :-)

Comment: sorry, actually whole comment not submitted. org.dom4j.Document (from dom4j library) and org.json.JSONObject (from Android lib).. yes. Signature= public Document getPhotoGalleryDisplay(final RequestContext context), in this method I have written logic of getting data from solr and making of xml document. Actually I want to make json document in place of xml document from SolrDocumentList. Hope now you will get me. waiting for a sample example.

Comment: Ok, here is my confusion coming: from one side you have `public org.dom4j.Document getPhotoGallery(RequestContext context) {...}`. And from another side you have `public org.dom4j.Document convertDoctoJson() {...}`. They both return the same type of return - i.e. `org.dom4j.Document` which is abstraction over XML document. My specific question: where JSON is coming into logic? Is it correct assumption you actually looking for transformation from `org.dom4j.Document` to `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: Ok, you are correct, it's not correct assumption. So could you guide how do I directly make json document  from SolrDocumentList. Actually I was not able to make direct document so tried from xml document to json document. My main concern is to replace xml document from json document as it is very light. Hope now you will get me.

Comment: Cool, so now the problem is more clear, but not 100% :-) Let me ask you this: did you consider using pure `HttpClient` with `&wt=json`? It is not the same as using `SolrJClient` I know. If `HttpClient` is not an option - then smth like `new JSONObject(qRespone.toString())` (assuming `qResponse` is the response from SolrJ client). Usually it is not a use-case to transform response to JSON directly. You can think - what you will do with such JSON? If your future usage would look like (sorry for syntax) `json.getField("response").getArray("docs").get(0).getField("id")`, maybe it's not worth it :)

Comment: Hello.. Still I am not able to move ahead..

Comment: new JSONObject(qRespone.toString()), ...after that what to do. json.getField("response").getArray("docs").get(0).getField("‌​id")(What to do with this one) . I passed response from SolrJ client in JSONObject like this JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rsp.toString());.. but not able to move ahead to get my desired wish, transform it into json document. Please offer a sample code.

Comment: From my understanding JSONObject is JSON document itself :) Java as a platform offers different ways to work with JSON format. One of them is JSONObject (Android ). Here are more: ObjectNode (Jackson), JsonObject (Gson), etc. - choose library of your flavour. Do u have any preferences? In other words - what do u wish to do with JSON document afterwards? Print it to console?

Comment: No... I will not print it on console, I would use method of this class at runtime in a jsp. So that this method return json document at runtime, when we hit jsp.  No,  I have not any preferences. But want to go with better one. I am not as much knowledgeable to judge which one is better. So please guide me.

Comment: hi..Paul No response?

Comment: Man, sorry for missing this.. My point is that `SolrDocumentList` API is pretty much similar to JSON document API, so it doesn't worth it to transform Solr response to JSON. Just please take a look into some projects on GitHub - https://github.com/gnanasundarams/comparison-tool/blob/66ed29c9d2cc43f65b96fbade6789726eea5a577/web/compare.jsp or https://github.com/cnyangqi/itg/blob/3e27a1cf11a6b0753479f7e47b8395852a9757e1/WebContent/nfwl/solr/index.jsp. This should give you basic hints how to use `SolrDocumentList` in your JSP. Hope this will help somehow :)

Comment: thanks so much Paul, try to follow you.